# How to get the public IP address of current user in Lightning component hosted on public community page

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

How would I get the IP address of the current user, when the user using a custom lightning component on a public community page?

Using this Apex code:

```
Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('SourceIp');
```

Throws error:

> Guest users must never have a session ID created as it would be a
>   security problem.

Comment: You might try [getting it in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841164/1492485).

Comment: https://sfdcian.com/salesforce-get-ip-address-of-community-user-guest-and-logged-in-customer-user/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Adrian Larson, I can get the public IP address using JavaScript.

**JavaScript helper method**

```
getPublicIPAddress: function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp=", true);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            let ipAddress = request.responseText;
            console.log(ipAddress);
        } else {
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
            console.log(request.statusText);
        }
    }
    request.onerror = function () {
        // There was a connection error of some sort
        console.log(request.statusText);
    }
    request.send();
},
```

NOTE: you may need to [add a Remote Site Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm)

Comment: I have tried this with a postman application, its provide IP address information. But, when I tried this in Salesforce LWC, I got an error "Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources because their origin is not included in the content security policy header"

Comment: I have added the "https://api.ipify.org" host URL in the Remote Site Setting. Even though I am getting the above error.

Comment: @Chintan - have you added a Content Security Policy (CSP)?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. After your comment, I search for that and add API host URL in the CSP. It's working fine.

Once again thanks.